# What's an adequate data structure for managing geometric subdivisions of a square?

Tags: computational-geometry

I'm looking for a data structure that can manage the data of a rectangle object (O LxH) as well as all the subdivision (internal partitions) of the rectangle object.

One should be able to add more partitions, as well as to access to the existing partitions. Each partition should be treated as another rectangle object (O LxH).

I was thinking I could use a BSP tree but I think that would probably be an over-sophisticated solution for my problem.

Example in the figure

[image]

the partition 'B' should be another object with an Origin, a Length, and an Height.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you definitely need some kind of tree.

You mention that you're worried that a BSP tree might be over sophisticated for this problem -- that depends on how robust you need the solution to be.  You might also want to consider whether objects can be partitioned into more than two pieces -- if not, then you could use a binary tree.

Basically, each node in the tree would have a size and shape, and child (partition) nodes.  Also, the node would be responsible for ensuring that the sizes and shapes of its children make sense -- i.e. that they don't overlap, they fill the entire parent, they don't go outside the parent.

Accessing the partitions could be accomplished by giving each node a relative id with respect to its parent.  The first child gets `relativeID = 0`, second child 1, etc.  Repeat this for each node's children at every level.  Then you can write a method that takes in a list of relative IDs, and uses that to traverse the tree and find the correct partition (each level strips off one relative ID, in order to move to the next level).

Answer (score 0):

The basic implementation is

```
struct Node
{
  vector<Node*> vChildNodes;
  double x0,y0,x1,y1;
};
```

...and typically you will need to add recursive split()- and locate()-methods.

What you try to implement looks similar to a Quadtree -- see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree or a kd-tree, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree. You can try existing implementations.